# Can't compile project on Linux using Kotlin 1.2.70

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

After updtate Kotlin from 1.2.61 to 1.2.70 I get this error when try to comlipe the project Android Gradle plugin v3.1.4

```
 Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 
 ':app:debugImplementationDependenciesMetadata'.
  > Could not resolve project :appstart.
 Required by:
     project :app
  > Unable to find a matching variant of project :appstart:
      - Variant 'debugApiElements':
          - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
          - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
          - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
          - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
          - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'common' and found incompatible value 'androidJvm'.
      - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements':
          - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
          - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
          - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
          - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
          - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'common' and found incompatible value 'androidJvm'.
      - Variant 'releaseApiElements':
          - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
          - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
          - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
          - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
          - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'common' and found incompatible value 'androidJvm'.
      - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements':
          - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
          - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
          - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
          - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
          - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'common' and found incompatible value 'androidJvm'.
```

I'm able to compile this project on Mac OS without any problem. And I have 0 common modules.

Anything I could do to workaround this problem?

UPD:
Afterupdating Android Studio Gradle plugin to 3.2.0-rc03 I have a bit different stack trace

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 
':app:debugImplementationDependenciesMetadata'.
> Could not resolve project :appstart.
 Required by:
     project :app
  > Cannot choose between the following variants of project :appstart:
      - kapt
      - kaptAndroidTest
      - kaptAndroidTestDebug
      - kaptDebug
      - kaptRelease
      - kaptTest
      - kaptTestDebug
      - kaptTestRelease
    All of them match the consumer attributes:
      - Variant 'kapt':
          - Found artifactType 'processed-jar' but wasn't required.
          - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'common' but no value provided.
      - Variant 'kaptAndroidTest':
          - Found artifactType 'processed-jar' but wasn't required.
          - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'common' but no value provided.
      - Variant 'kaptAndroidTestDebug':
          - Found artifactType 'processed-jar' but wasn't required.
          - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'common' but no value provided.
      - Variant 'kaptDebug':
          - Found artifactType 'processed-jar' but wasn't required.
          - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'common' but no value provided.
      - Variant 'kaptRelease':
          - Found artifactType 'processed-jar' but wasn't required.
          - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'common' but no value provided.
      - Variant 'kaptTest':
          - Found artifactType 'processed-jar' but wasn't required.
          - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'common' but no value provided.
      - Variant 'kaptTestDebug':
          - Found artifactType 'processed-jar' but wasn't required.
          - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'common' but no value provided.
      - Variant 'kaptTestRelease':
          - Found artifactType 'processed-jar' but wasn't required.
          - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'common' but no value provided.
```

Comment: This is a breaking change in 1.2.70, please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26834 for updates/workarounds.